# getting around recursion when dumping a node?

Tags: theming, nodes, debugging

I'm working on a template and I'm using `kpr()` from `devel` to look at the values defined in `$variables`. One of them is the node in question, and what gets displayed is a big infinity sign indicating recursion.

Is there any way to get around this to have a look at what data I actually have available in the node object?

What is it in the node that creates the recursion?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot get around this in the sense that `kpr($variables)` will always display this unless you hack the implementation of krumo (the library that `kpr` uses).

Use

```
kpr($variables['node'])
```

to display the node instead.

Also, the node page has a *devel* tab that does exactly this.

Comment: In the devel tab you also have the option to see the "load" and "render" sub-tabs. The load sub-tab is like dpm($variables['node']); and the render sub-tab is like dpm($variables);